# Ionic2 Native - Camera - Get real path from a given URI on Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, apache-cordova

I'm following this tutorial:

http://devfanaticblog.com/working-with-camera-in-ionic-2-and-ionic-native/

I'm runing the application on an `Android` phone.

```
$ ionic run android
```

It works properly with only one exception:

```
Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
```

is returning somthing like:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1792
```

which is not working. I need the real path, for example:

```
/storage/sdcard/Downloads/ionic.png
```

These are some of the commands I ran to make the code work.

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/camera
```

Here is the source code of the plugin: `github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera`

There I can see there is already a function which does exactly what I need.

```
public static String getRealPath(Uri uri, CordovaInterface cordova) {...}
```

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/android/FileHelper.java#L44

**My question is:**

> How do I make use of that function on the file: `home.ts` in order to make the URI conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI
```

This should return the native path for the image.

Comment: This didn't work. If you check this: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/camera/index.ts#L12 you will see that `Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI` should return `content:// on Android` while `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` should return the the real path.